# How to hide secret strings from application users in desktop installable application?

Tags: java, encryption, desktop-application, password-protection, universal-hashing

I have a desktop installable java application which uses some third party jars.These jars need secret key as license.I want third party license info hidden from user of my application.
Also we have the limitation that we cannot make network calls to validate license so it has to be stored and validated within the application.
Encryption require key to be saved in file system hence it can be read by user.
Keeping key in java files will also not help as classes can be decompiled and read.Do we have other ways to do it ?

Comment: There is no way to do that

Comment: Also "hiding" != "encryption". This is basically [Security through Obscurity, and a well-known antipattern](https://pwning.owasp-juice.shop/part2/security-through-obscurity.html).

Comment: You can try storing the encrypted key in the database. If I understand the question correctly